# String Approximation (Fetching the nearest matched String from Dictionary)

Tags: java, string, string-matching, approximation

Is there any String Matching code or Algorithm which gives us the approximately matched string from the dictionay(contains pre-defined Set of Strings)?

For example: If there are 10 String in the dictionary (Set of Strings), if user input some String, then the algorithm should tell you the near matched string from the dictionary. Its would be great, if i get the matched string with the matched value (or percentage).

Comment: Welcome to SO. How big is the lookup dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to use lucene library it has a package called `org.apache.lucene.search.spell` you can use it easily. it provide 3 algorithms  **NGramDistance, LevensteinDistance, JaroWinklerDistance**. [try this](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/spell/SpellChecker.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate a [Levenshtein distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) between your String and strings in your dictionary to find the closest matches. This may not be the best for spell checking as it gives no favour to letter being swapped around or words which are phonetically similar. e.g. question is closer to resting than kwizchum.

For more examples, you can read up on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximate_string_matching

Answer (score 1):

I just wanted to add that StringUtils also has [a convenient Levenshtein Distance method](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#getLevenshteinDistance%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) since version 3.0

```
public static int getLevenshteinDistance(CharSequence s,
                     CharSequence t)
```

After that it's just as simple as iterating through the collection and remembering the closest match:

```
public static Object findClosestMatch(Collection<?> collection, Object target) {
    int distance = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    Object closest = null;
    for (Object compareObject : collection) {
        int currentDistance = StringUtils.getLevenshteinDistance(compareObject.toString(), target.toString());
        if(currentDistance < distance) {
            distance = currentDistance;
            closest = compareObject;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Note that the method above does require collection to be null-safe and toString() to be sensfully implemented.

Comment: Isn't there a "distance = currentDistance" missing just inside the if?

Comment: Woops indeed, I've had to remove some specific code, seems I was too eager :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) techinque.

The simple idea you have four basic operations:

- Insertion (hell -> hell **o**)
- Replacement (nice -> **r** ice)
- Deletion (bowlin **g** -> bowlin)
- Swapping (brohter -> bro **th** er)

You algorithm should calculate the distance between your word and every word in dictionary. The smallest distance means that this word matches more accurate with given input.